# Laravel- how to get "old" value from radio button in foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-blade

I want to retrieve `old` selected radio button after validation of form fails.
I found solutions for normal radio buttons but mine is in `foreach` loop in laravel blade view. I tried the solutions for normal radios but it doesn't work
Here's my view:

```
@foreach($projects as $key => $value)
<tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="id_project" value="{{ $value->id_project }}"  ></td>
    <td>{{ $value->id_project }}</td>
    <td>{{ $value->tytul }}</td>
    <td>{{ $value->koszt }} </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare `old()` and iterated value.

```
@foreach($projects as $key => $value)
<tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="id_project" value="{{ $value->id_project }}"  {{ old('id_project') == $value->id_project ? 'checked' : ''}} ></td>
    <td>{{ $value->id_project }}</td>
    <td>{{ $value->tytul }}</td>
    <td>{{ $value->koszt }} </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Great ! Thank you very much